# Are there conditions under which Georgian nouns omit the "-ი" case ending?

Tags: morphology, nouns, georgian

In Georgian most nouns in the nominative case end with "-ი" (-i), most other nouns end in another vowel.

In cases other than the nominative this ending may be replaced with a different ending but the endings are not usually altogether omitted.

However I am sure that I have occasionally seen some nouns without this final -ი and just ending with a bare consonant.

Is this really possible or have I imagined it? Under which conditions can it occur?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based mainly on Aronson and Kiziria's *Georgian Language and Culture: A Continuing Course*, the most common situations in which Georgian nouns that take -i in the nominative can end in the bare consonant are the following:

1) vocative forms of proper nouns, e.g. "დავითი/Daviti" (nom.), but "დავით/Davit" (voc.),

2) when as an attribute in agreement with a noun in the dative or adverbial case (i.e. it is declined just like a consonant-stem adjective), e.g. "ბოთლ/botl" (bottle) in "ლინდსი ლოჰანი დღეში ორ ბოთლ არაყს სვამს/Lindsi Lohani dgheshi or botl araqs svams" (Lindsay Lohan drinks two bottles of vodka a day),

3) first names preceding family names, titles etc., e.g. "დავით აღმაშენებელი/Davit Aghmashenebeli" (David the Builder) but "დავითი/Daviti", or "მიხეილ სააკაშვილი/Mikheil Saak'ashvili" but "მიხეილი/Mikheili"

4) the first element of some fixed expressions, mainly involving points of the compass, e.g. "დასავლეთ საქართველო/Dasavlet Sakartvelo" (Western Georgia), but "დასავლეთი/dasavleti" (west).

Comment: Aha! #2 was exactly what I was looking for. I could find that it was possible for adjectives and that nouns and adjectives decline alike but my info stated that when nouns are used attributively they are always in the genetive and don't decline, which contradicts the statement that nouns and adjectives are alike. I know about the proper nouns and hyphenated compounds but didn't consider those to be what I was looking for. Do you have chapter or page number references for Aronson & Kiziria?

Comment: I'm glad it was helpful!  I have the 1999 edition of Aronson & Kiziria and I got most of the information from pp. 338-341.  If you have another edition, you'll find the information right at the beginning of the Grammar Review section, which comes after the reading selections.  For the Lindsay Lohan example, I just Googled "ბოთლ არაყს" and it was the first thing that came up, but obviously, you could Google similar things for more examples of this usage.